# Slide a repeated background image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a background image with a bunch of logos that I want to gradually slide left to simulate a stock ticker. I know there are plugins to slide multiple images, but this works best in my scenario.

How would I progressively add on the new class, as the following:

```
<div class="background-slider-start"></div>

.background-slider-start {
    background: url('my-image.png') repeat-x 0 0;
}
.background-slider-end {
    background: url('my-image.png') repeat-x -5000px 0;
}

$('.background-slider-start).addClass('background-slider-end', 30000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addClass` doesn't accept duration, you can try using CSS3 transition:

```
.background-slider-start {
    background: url('my-image.png') repeat-x 0 0;
    -webkit-transition: background 30s;
    -moz-transition: background 30s;
    -o-transition: background 30s;
    transition: background 30s;
}
```

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('.background-slider-start').toggleClass('background-slider-end');
}, 30000);
```